# Prove that $\ \{(x,y):1<x,y<3\}=A$ is an open set

Tags: general-topology

What I tried:

Let$\ P_0=(x_0,y_0)$ then $\ 1<x_0,y_0<3$

Let$\ B_r(P_0) \in A$ with$\ r=min\{x_0-1,3-y_0\}$

Let$\ Q=(x,y) \in B_r(P_0) $ then

$$\ ||(x-x_0,y-y_0)||<r$$

If $\ r=x_0-1$ then $\ x-x_0≤|x-x_0|≤||(x-x_0,y-y_0)||<r=x_0-1$ so we conclude that $\ 1<x$

If $\ r=3-y_0$ then $\ y-y_0≤|y-y_0|≤||(x-x_0,y-y_0)||<r=3-y_0$ so we conclude that $\ y<3$

So$\ Q=(x,y) \in A$, then,$\ A$ is open

Any thoughts on this? ($\ ||‧||$ is the norm)

Comment: Do you know that given a continuous function, preimage of open set is open? And do you know intersection of two open sets is also open?

Comment: I've seen some proofs using that, but I want to solve the problem using balls (since that's what I have been using in my course).

Comment: In addition to @edm's excellent remarks, it is also known that a finite product of open sets is open, and your set is simply $A=(1,\infty)\times(-\infty,3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks fine. However, I suggest some modifications for the two lines that start with "if".

You don't need separate cases for the value of $r$, and you need to show why $|x-x_0| \leq || (x-x_0,y-y_0)||$.

So, you can write:

$x_0-x \leq |x-x_0| = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2} \leq \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} < r \leq x_0-1 $

$y-y_0 \leq |y-y_0| = \sqrt{(y-y_0)^2} \leq  \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2} < r \leq 3-y_0$

Answer (score 0):

A = (1,3)x(1,3) is the product of two open sets, hence open.

Comment: It is indeed an open set, if the topology is assigned by taking the product topology.  It seems to me the OP attempts to use a metric in the plane (based on Euclidean distance) to define a topology.  Sometimes it is best to wait for the OP to clarify what the problem is about.